# C# projects to practice on while learning

Tags: c#

Good evening, 
I am currently learning C# on Treehouse, Pluralsight, and Microsoft Virtual Academy. I wanted to get some ideas on what kind of small simple programs I can begin working so I can sharpen the lessons I've learned so far.

Thanks,
Ed

Comment: try http://codekata.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever I'm learning a new language, I solve ProjectEuler problems:

https://projecteuler.net/

These is a list of maths problems, the type you need to write a program to solve.

The opening problems are trivial, and then the questions get progressively harder.